# Umrah condition for women of age 50 years

Tags: umrah, mahram, non-mahram

My mother is planning to perform Umrah but she could not travel with her Mahram.
My mother will travel to Makkah from Pakistan and her brother from UK and then they will perform Umrah together. Does Islam allow to perform Umrah in this case for a women with age to 50 years?

Comment: Well some madhabs would accept it  under some conditions but would saudi authorities accept this?

Answer (score -1):

In short **NO**, for details here is proper [Fatwa-Is there an age at which a woman no longer needs a mahram?](https://islamqa.info/en/52703)
May Allah guide us all to the right path.

Comment: Would someone please explain to me why this answer was downvoted? Thanks!

Comment: I wold also like to know.